# How to create a read-only snapshot in btrfs?

Tags: mount, btrfs, backup

As far as I understand, the snapshots made by `btrfs subvolume snapshot` are writable by default and are visible at a certain path under the mountpoint of your btrfs volume.

How to setup the system so that there is a gurantee during the normal operation of the system that nothing is written to the snapshot? But without making it invisible to the users (i.e., it should remain accessible for reading by any users with respect to their permissions).

(For now, I've just `chmod og-rwx /.snapshots` where my snapshots are mapped to. But that doesn't fulfill the second of my wishes, and also the guarantee is not strong enough: a process with root's rights could spoil something there.)

Does one need to do some tricks with `mount` to achieve this goal?

Comment: In LVM, there is AFAIU a dedicated `lvchange --permission r` for this purpose.

Comment: Comparing the default situation in btrfs (i.e., *writable* snapshots) to LVM: [Can LVM snapshots be writable?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19210/4319).

Comment: What distro are you using? Ubuntu ships with an old version of btrfs-tools, and thus does not provide read-only snapshots.

Answer (score 6):

- Create a read-only subvolume (as root):

  ```
  btrfs subvolume snapshot -r /path/to/mounted/subvolume /path/to/snapshot
  ```
- Change an already existing subvolume/snapshot to read-only:

  ```
  btrfs property set /path/to/snapshot ro true
  ```
- Check current status for an existing subvolume:

  ```
  btrfs property get /path/to/snapshot ro
  ```

(Note that this did not work on older versions of Ubuntu.)

Comment: Doesn't work for me either on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: It works on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky Can we at least try to generalise this away from Ubuntu.  I expect the version of btrfs, or at least its user-space tools is more relevant.   We know at least that v0.19 of the command line tool didn't work.  Can we get a version number for that does work?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Ubuntu?

Ubuntu ships with an old version of btrfs-tools (aka "btrfs-progs"), and thus the userland tools do not support read-only snapshots.

See this bug (and it's parent bug):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/btrfs-tools/+bug/924621

Answer (score 1):

According to [Btrfs wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/#News), read-only snapshots are available since Linux 2.6.38. So make sure you have a recent kernel. Apart from that, you should be just able to do it using `ro` mount option (`mount -o [other-options],ro ...`).