# How to create a snapshot in btrfs, and then rollback to it after some work?

Tags: restore, btrfs, backup, sandbox

What are the commands to use in btrfs in case I want to:

1. create a ([read-only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18912/4319)) snapshot of a volume;
2. (do some experiments in the volume);
3. and then rollback the volume to the snapshot?

Comment: [Here are the commands for this scenario in LVM](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18913/how-to-create-a-read-only-snapshot-in-lvm-and-then-rollback-to-it-after-some-wor/18914#18914).

Answer (score 22):

```
# take a read-only snapshot:
btrfs sub snap -r fs snapshot

... do things on fs

# rolling back:
btrfs sub del fs # at which point you'll lose those things you've done
                 # if you want to preserve them, just rename fs instead

btrfs sub snap snapshot fs # reinstate snapshot as a read+write fs
btrfs sub del snapshot # delete the non-longer needed read-only snapshot
```

Comment: I like how you `snapshot` the snapshot over the filesystem, instead of attempting to move it. It's elegant in analogy to copying the snapshot, rather than attempting to use and alter it.

You might mention that this sequence will end up deleting everything done in the "... do things" step.

Comment: Here is what happened when I tried to restore the snapshot.  I have a btrfs filesystem mounted at /mnt/sdc1, and I created a read-only snapshot named 20170917.

`btrfs sub del .`
>   Delete subvolume (no-commit): '/mnt/sdc1'
>  ERROR: cannot delete '/mnt/sdc1': Invalid argument

or 

btrfs sub snap 20170917/ .
Create a snapshot of '20170917/' in './20170917'
ERROR: cannot snapshot '20170917/': File exists

Comment: Sorry about the poor formatting in the above comment.  Markdown for comments is braindead.

Comment: @Harold, sound like you can't delete the root volume that way. There may be ways to do it, but I have to admit it's been 5 years since I last used `btrfs` as I gave up on it as it had too many stability, performance and reliability issues. It may be more usable now, but the end of the story is that I'm not so familiar with it anymore (not to mentioned that it has probably evolved a lot as well since).

Comment: Thanks.  It seems to be the best choice on Linux right now for a modern filesystem, if I can figure out how to use it.

Comment: It should be noted that nowadays there is no need to create a snapshot of a snapshot to change its read-only state. You can just use `btrfs property set "$path_to_snapshot" ro true/false` to set it to either true or false which is probably faster.

Comment: I don't get the "rename" part. Mind to create an example?

Comment: Xbian says this upon executing first command: ERROR: Could not statfs: No such file or directory
When i use / instead of fs, then it says "Create a readonly snapshot of '/' in './snapshot'" yet second command fails with "ERROR: Could not destroy subvolume/snapshot: Invalid argument" when used "/" or ends with "..no such file" when used "fs" (in second command).

Answer (score 5):

Try from the other side: create R/W snapshot, use it as new main one, do "some experiments" on old one, then just drop contents of old.

Article "[BTRFS Fun](https://www.funtoo.org/BTRFS_Fun#Using_snapshots_for_system_recovery_.28aka_Back_to_the_Future.29)" can be helpful.

Comment: the linked article no longer exists :(